# Windows Embedded CE 6.0 Booting from read-only medium

Tags: embedded, read-only, windows-ce

I couldn't find anything on the net about this.

Do you guys know of any books, tutorials or MSDN article that explains how to do this?

Does CE support something like a RAM-Disk to save run-time changed configuration files to?
The software we use fetches the configuration files from an FTP Server on boot and saves it locally.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Windows CE supports several modes for files storing, one of them is called [Objects Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms900311.aspx). This mode is basically a RAM disk that is merged with the ROM file system. Unfortunately, this mode cannot be activated by a user, it must be configured during the production of the Windows CE OS image of your device, so your only choice is to contact the manufacturer of the device and request them to provide you an OS image with this mode activated.